# Absorption probabilities in birth and death process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

For a birth and death process with parameters $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i$ representing the birth and death rates respectively, define $u_m$ to be the absorption of probability of the process into state $0$, starting from $m$.

The book by Karlin and Taylor mentions that either $u_m=1$ for all $m$ or $u_m\to 0$ as $m\to \infty$. They mention that this fact has a simple probabilistic proof, but I can't seem to get around it.

Any help?

Comment: You have read the proof but you can't understand it, or you merely know that there is such a proof but you can't find it?

Comment: They haven't given a proof actually. Only the result is stated. They have mentioned that a probabilistic proof exists. I can't work it out.